# Function returns wrong value

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, return

It's a program that uses recursion to convert string to int
The code always outputs 17 when it's supposed to output 1234
and when I add a digit to that number it adds 1 to that output
for example if it's supposed to output 12345 it outputs 18

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int convertToInteger(string numberStr)
{
    if (numberStr.size()==0)  return result;
    convertToInteger (numberStr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string numberStr("1234");
    cout << numberInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to know that this exists in `<string>` as `std::stoi(numberStr)`.

Comment: Didn't the compiler at least notify you that your `int convertToInt` does not have a return statement?

Comment: +1 for a complete, short program that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: I don't see how `convertToInteger` would ever return if `numberStr.size() > 0`.  (Even if you include a return statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return` before `convertToInt (numberStr)`;

Comment: Obvious Method Glitch* indeed

Comment: I really would like to know how this helped. `result` is never set, and there is no recursion, `convertToInteger`  is calling itself endlessly when the string has a size > 0.

Comment: @MarkKanemura: Always compile with warning messages enabled. When I compiled your program, my compiler said: "x.cc: In function `‘int convertToInt(std::string)’`: error: control reaches end of non-void function`.